# Ionic: Differentiate between clicking on the list-item and on a button in the list-item

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created a list with items each containing a button in the right. I have written two different functions, one for handling click directly on the item and one for the button at right.

The problem is clicking on the button result in calling both of the functions.

How can I edit the .html (or if not possible, then .js) so that clicking on the item (excluding the button area) will call a function and clicking on the right button will call another function.

[CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/frrahat/pen/qRbOKe)

HTML:

```
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat='item in list' class='list-group-item' 
            item="item"
            ng-click="clicker(item)" >
            <a class="item item-button-right">
                <h2>Item {{item.id}}</h2>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <button class="button button-assertive" ng-click="onRemoveClick(item)">
                    <i class="icon icon ion-close"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </a>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

AngularJS:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('list_controller', function($scope) {

    $scope.clicker = function(item){
    alert('Item Clicked: '+item.id)
};

    $scope.onRemoveClick = function(item){
    alert('Remove Clicked: '+item.id)
};

$scope.list = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 },
    { id: 4 },
    { id: 5 }
];

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can by using [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). Example below

**View**

```
 ng-click="onRemoveClick(item, $event);"
```

**Js**

```
 $scope.onRemoveClick = function (item, $event) {
     $event.stopPropagation();
 }
```

Comment: I don't want to use left button. Clicking on the item (excluding the button area) should do a job and clicking on the right button should do another job.

Comment: Well, if you insist, try put stopPropagation on ng-click. ng-click="onRemoveClick(item); $event.stopPropagation();"

Comment: Yes, the update solves the problem. Thank you. The HTML you posted before does not solve the problem. Please edit or remove the HTML code to mark your answer as accepted.